# Using substitute() on a specific column in a table to change dates

Tags: excel, vba, substitution, tablecolumn

I'm trying to use substitute() on a specific column in a table. All the dates are entered 13.03.2019. I need to replace the "." with "/" to be able to use them in other formulas.

How would I let this formula change the whole column?
I've managed to do a single cell.

This works for a single cell outside the table. But I need to change the dates in that whole column in the table.

```
    wsDormant.Range("C8") = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(wsDormant.Range("C8"), ".", "/")
```

This is for the table column:

```
With wsDormant.ListObjects("Table_Dormant_Stock")
        .Range.AutoFilter

        'Convert date format
        .ListColumns("Days Last Sold").DataBodyRange.Formula = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.ListColumns("Days Last Sold").DataBodyRange, ".", "/")

End With
```

It should all change from 15.03.2019 to 15/03/2019

Comment: Use `Replace()` not a worksheet function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Substitute or Replace in an assignment to a range of cells and you can't apply a formula to the entire column that references itself (as in your attempt).

If it's only a small table, you can use your single cell solution in a lazy loop through the ListColumn:

```
Dim raCell as Range

For each raCell in wsDormant.ListObjects("Table_Dormant_Stock").ListColumns("Days Last Sold").DataBodyRange
    raCell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(raCell, ".", "/")
Next
```

Alternatively, as Scott has pointed out, using the native VBA function Replace is more efficient:

```
Dim raCell as Range

For each raCell in wsDormant.ListObjects("Table_Dormant_Stock").ListColumns("Days Last Sold").DataBodyRange
    raCell = Replace(raCell, ".", "/")
Next
```

That said, both solutions are still inefficient if you're working through a large list.

A more efficient solution is to create a temporary working column using the SUBSTITUTE function:

```
With wsDormant.ListObjects("Table_Dormant_Stock").ListColumns.Add
    .DataBodyRange.Formula = "=SUBSTITUTE([@[Days Last Sold]], ""."", ""/"")"
    wsDormant.ListObjects("Table_Dormant_Stock").ListColumns("Days Last Sold").DataBodyRange.Value = .DataBodyRange.Value
    .Delete
End With
```

The other efficient solution is to copy all values to an array, loop through that array, then copy the updated values back to the spreadsheet:

```
Dim varArray As Variant, i As Integer

With wsDormant.ListObjects("Table_Dormant_Stock").ListColumns("Days Last Sold")
    varArray = .DataBodyRange
    For i = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
        varArray(i, 1) = Replace(varArray(i, 1), ".", "/")
    Next i
    .DataBodyRange = varArray
End With
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael, the 3rd option "efficient Substitute" seems to have solved the problem.